# Can a Chrome Extension expose a virtual camera and render to it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, mediastream

I know that I can render to a peer connection (for example, [screen sharing with getDisplayMedia](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/getdisplaymedia), or [streaming from canvas to peer connection with captureStream](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-pc/)).

But is it possible, using a Chrome Extension, to create and render to a virtual camera, so that the user can then choose that camera inside any/all of the popular web videochat applications (Zoom for web, Google Hangouts, etc.)? I'm new to WebRTC, but I'm guessing this would mean somehow adding a new mediaDevice/videoSource.

(I realize a similar result can be achieved by rendering to a canvas in a separate tab and then "presenting" the tab to the videochat, but that's not quite what I'm after.)

Comment: There is no such API.

Comment: Right. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this [proof of concept](https://github.com/spite/virtual-webcam) .

Comment: I ended up going with a native (non-web) approach back in April when I asked this question, but this looks like exactly what I was looking for at that point. Accepting answer for others who might come across this. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome. Is there any way to access and use this virtual cam in a desktop zoom client?

Comment: Without a browser API for creating a "real" virtual camera I don't think there is. The extension does not create a "sytem-recognizable" virtual camera (which would be required for other apps to pick it up on their media devices list).

It "injects" a new stream into the list returned by the APIs built into the browser, so the "virtual camera" will be available only in the browser.

It does so by [monkeypatching MediaDevices.prototype](https://github.com/spite/virtual-webcam/blob/master/js/media-devices.js) which is actually a pretty neat trick ;)